# Flashing image in div when I use background-image css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div in my webpage, it is the two possible option the user can choose from. I set each div background with css (background-image). The images are preloaded, when the site loads. There is two possible state, when an option selected xxx_image_enabled.png are set as a background image, when the option is not selected, xxx_image_disabled.png is set as a background image. In some browser (Chrome) it is flashing a little bit. I set the background-image property with jQuery.

The css looks like this:

```
.option-div{
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any idea what causes the flashing? After a refresh it disappears.

Comment: create a fiddle. It will help to understand the problems.

Comment: can you paste your jquery code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refrain from setting original styles in your scripts to keep your code unobtrusive and separated. You can set the background-image in CSS then change the value of it later in jQuery.

Not sure how your HTML is set up but make sure your CSS is loaded before your script in the HTML order. If your script is loaded first, you will have some rendering issues. Put your `<link>` or `<style>` before the `<script>` that uses it.

I'm just guessing these suggestions since I can't see the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the jQuery is causing the event to repeat.  To fix this, I suggest using a jQuery .stop within the function.

Consider:

```
$("#option-div").stop(true,false).animate({ //this is assuming you are using animate, swap this out for the event you are using
```

//just to make you aware, if you set this to false,false it will skip the event and go straight to the finished outcome, in this case the animation would not trigger.

Also, consider using an if statement to prevent the event from being called, if it is already active.

Consider:

```
if($("#option-div").not(':animated')){
else { // your code here
```

It would be easier to understand the problem and help you if you provide your jQuery code, I would have commented but don't have 50 rep yet.